# Python Find_Element_by_xxx has suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, selenium

Update: Figured this out. If I run the script as an administrator on the Server 2012 instance it works. Something must have changed on the server between yesterday and today that change some permissions.

When using selenium I'm unable to get the element I need on on Windows Server 2012. I just get "None". If I try to access an element that doesn't exist I get the appropriate NoSuchElementException so it seems to be finding it.

Everything worked fine until yesterday and for some reason stopped today. The code also works fine when I run it on Windows 10.

I'm using the same iedriver from a shared disk so it's not that.

Here's the html code. Nothing is changing before or after I make this call.

```
<div id="root">some text</div>
```

```
print(browser.find_element_by_id("root"))

None
```

```
print(browser.find_element_by_id("root").text)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_id("root").print
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If I do the same call for an element that does not exist, then I get the expected not found exception.

```
print(browser.find_element_by_id("none"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    print(browser.find_element_by_id("none"))
  File "C:\Users\A1B4CZZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\A1B4CZZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\A1B4CZZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\A1B4CZZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == [id="none"]
```

A further update to add to this. If I select all elements on the page I get them returned but they are ALL None when I print them:

```
>>> elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')
>>> print(len(elems))
8559

>>> for elem in elems:
    print(elem)


None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please take a minute to format your question properly. You have your code formatted in a quote instead of code which makes it hard to read. Also your question is not clear. The code you posted shows that the element is not being found... thus the `None` on the first line and the error on the next. Clearly that element either no longer exists, you need to add a wait, or the format of the page has changed (possibly moving the element into an `IFRAME`), etc. So what's the question? We can't offer a new locator with no HTML to look at.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. The form to enter my question did that automatically. 
The issue is that the element is found but returns none - but only on the windows 2012 machine. If I put an invalid ID then it returns a NoSuchElementException as expected.

Comment: On the windows 10 machine it's working as expected and returning the element and the inner text

Comment: Is the page automatically refreshing at some interval? It's hard to say what the issue is. You'd have to search the DOM and see if the expected element is actually there or not. I'm not sure what `None` means in this context or what it should actually return. I would do something like `print(elem.getAttribute("innerHTML")`.

Comment: what do you see when you do `print(driver.page_source)`?

Comment: Have you tried `$("#root")[0]` in the web console? Do you see the element node as oupt?

Comment: print(driver.page_source) returns nothing
$("#root")[0] returns undefined (but it also does that on my Windows 10 machine where this script works)

Comment: If I look at the page source or search in developer tools, the element is there

Comment: $("#root").innerText in the console returns what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try with `textContent`.

```
print(browser.find_element_by_id("root").get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Comment: Returns the following:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Answer (score 0):

Update: Figured this out. If I run the script as an administrator on the Server 2012 instance it works. Something must have changed on the server between yesterday and today that change some permissions.